# Why can't 2 NetworkManagers be used at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, server, unity-networking

This question is about new Unity UNet solution for networking.

I wanted to create a smooth transition from one server to another, but looks like I am not available to use more than one instance of NetworkManager in the same time. But why? What's the problem to use multiple server connections? Is there any possibility to connect to two servers at the same time?

Or another case: What if I want to use two servers: one for syncing positions, second for global values, like money or something, which is synced in MySQL database ? What I need to do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

For the 'global money' server or any server that is outside of the 'game' mechanics (player position, game objects, etc).  Create a web API on that server, perhaps a Restful API, then use HTTP Get/Put/Post calls from within your games unity server to interact with the web API.

This would allow multiple instances of game server to interact with it, as well as potentially allowing you to have direct access to it from web portals etc if so desired.

HTH